# File creating under root directory, strange response

Tags: java, file

This is not actually a question, but I need explanation. I was trying to create directory under C:// drive. So;

```
try {
            File f_paz = new File("c://Ekap_Pazarlik_xml" + file_currentDate + "//");

            File parent_z = f_paz.getParentFile();
            if (null != parent_z) {
                parent_z.mkdirs();
            }
            if (!f_paz.exists()) {
                f_paz.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried that and it gave me "Access Denied" error, so I tried all the solutions in the web. Nothing happened.

Strangely, I decided to put "space" after there;

```
File f_paz = new File("c://Ekap_Pazarlik_xml" + file_currentDate + "// ");
                                                                     here
```

just after `"// "`, and it worked. I was able to crate directory like that. I have no idea why it worked like that. Please provide me some explanation. Thanks !

Comment: `"C:/Ekap_whatever/"` is _not_ a file name but a directory name. Adding a space at the end would mean the file's name is a space with the rest being its path. Windows won't let you create a file with a blank name (although it seems to deny that silently) so that's why you only see the directory. Try a non-space character instead of space (e.g. `x`) and you see a file with that name being created in your directory.

Comment: I tried to crate Dİrectory not a file. Why it is not accepting without space ? what is the logic behind it ? I'm giving the path to File(path) it should accept it. Why do I need to put a space at the end. ? At least compiler should give me a proper error so I can handle it. Access denied is way too strange to that error.

Comment: I'll put my comment into an answer and add some more info. Sec.

Comment: I'm really glad. waiting for your answer. Thanks @Thomas !

Comment: Why are you using `//` on windows the separator is `\` (which in Java needs to be escaped as `\\`)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel in most cases Java can translate `/` into `\ ` for file paths.

Comment: You tried *all* the solutions on the web? How do we know you found them all? Or read them.

Comment: @Raedwald I've been looking about 3 days and there were not many different answers.

Comment: @Thomas As far as I know Windows does this (as I also know non-Java applications that resolve files using `/` correctly on Windows), but there might be a subtle differences between using `/` versus using `//`. But I see my previous comment was broken; it should have read: "Why are you using `//` on windows the separator is `\ ` (which in Java needs to be escaped as `\\ `)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f_paz.createNewFile();` will try to create a new file, not a directory. Many Windows systems won't allow you to create files in directly in `C:` so that's why you get the exception.

Since you want to create a directory and not a file use `f_paz.mkdir();` instead. You don't need the `"//"` at the end, btw.

What happens if you add the space, i.e. use path `"C:/Ekap_xxx/ "`? The system will see a path with a blank filename `" "` and a parent directory name `"Ekap_xxx"`. Now `parent_z` will refer to `"C:/Ekap_xxx"` and thus `parent_z.mkdirs();` will create directory `"Ekap_xxx"`. Now `f_paz.exists()` will return true since the filesystem seems to decide a file with an invalid name still exists (I'd have to look for some information on why that is so, it's hidden in the native code).